# Writing a list based on another list that is based on another list on Prolog

Tags: prolog

OK, that is freaking my brains out.

```
% Ok, that's how we find the occurrences of given element in list
% occurrences([a,b,c,a],a,X).
% -> X = 2.

occurrences([],_,0).
occurrences([X|Y],X,N):- occurrences(Y,X,W),N is W + 1.
occurrences([X|Y],Z,N):- occurrences(Y,Z,N),X\=Z.
```

But what if we are working with two lists? Let me explain.
Here we have fruits with Id, Name, Taste and Price.

```
%fruit(FId, N, T, M (M is for Money as P is for person)).
fruit(1, 'apple'            , sweet  , 5).
fruit(2, 'greenApple'       , bitter , 5).
fruit(3, 'grape'            , sweet  , 10).
fruit(4, 'peach'            , sweet  , 20).
fruit(5, 'orange'           , citric , 5).
fruit(6, 'tangerine'        , citric , 7).
fruit(7, 'banana'           , sweet  , 3).
fruit(8, 'lemon'            , citric , 6).
fruit(9, 'bitterMelons', citric , 12).
fruit(10,'grapefruit'       , citric , 8).

%person(PId, P).
person(1, 'ana').
person(2, 'john').

%ate(PId, FId).
ate(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]).
ate(2, [1, 3, 5, 8]).

person_ate(P, F, T, M) :-
person(PId, P),
ate(PId, FruitIds),
member(FId, FruitIds),
fruit(FId, F, T, M).
```

also, I have these rules to define if a fruit is expensive or not.

```
cheap_fruit(FId, F, T, M)                   :- fruit(FId, F, T, M), M =< 6.
expensive_fruit(FId, F, T, M)               :- fruit(FId, F, T, M), M > 15.
middleprice_fruit(FId, F, T, M)             :- fruit(FId, F, T, M), M > 6, M =< 12.
```

So, querying

```
person_ate('ana', F, _, _). or person_ate('ana', _, T, _).
```

i know what fruits ana ate and what types of fruit they are. But how can I count it?

Here's what I tried.

```
%occurrences(list, item in given list ,number of items).

occurrences(person_ate(_, _, _, _),_,0).

occurrences(person_ate(P, F, T, _),T,N):- 
            occurrences(person_ate(P, F, T, _),T,W),
            N is W + 1.
occurrences(person_ate(P, F, T, _, _),Z,N):- 
            occurrences(person_ate(P, F, T, _, _),Z,N),
            T\=Z.
```

Now, in theory, if I query

```
occurrences(person_ate('ana', _, T, _),T,N).
```

I would get how many sweet, bitter, and citric fruits she ate, instead I simply get

```
N = 0.
N = 1.
N = 2.
N = 3.
N = 4.
N = 5.
....
```

an so on forever (I mean i can execute this forever, and N would never cease to raise, and that's just not what I want). And if i query

```
occurrences(person_ate('ana', _, sweet, _),T,N).
```

or

```
occurrences(person_ate('ana', _, T, _),sweet,N).
```

it just returns

```
N = 0
N = 1,
T = sweet
N = 2,
T = sweet
N = 3,
T = sweet
N = 4,
T = sweet
N = 5,
T = sweet
....
```

and so on forever... This has to work in order to me recommend fruits. I want to recommend fruits based on the types of fruit the person ate, OR based on the "price rules" (the ones which determinates if a fruit is expensive or not), and for that I have to count how many sweet, bitter and citric fruits the person ate.

```
recommending_fruits :- 
    write('Choose someone '), 
    read(Person), 
    pessoa(X, Person), 
    ate(X, FruitIds),
    fruit(Y, _, T, _, _), filme(Y,N,T,_,_), write(N).
```

Comment: See max66's answer about metapredicates like `findall`. Regarding your predicate `occurrences`, you are confused about what the _ (underscore) represents. It will unify with anything. That is why in your implementation, the first clause unifies with any query of `occurrences\3` where the first argument can be unified with `person_ate(_,_,_,_)`, like your example `occurrences(person_ate('ana', _, T, _),T,N).`]

Answer (score 1):

> I know what fruits ana ate and what types of fruit they are. But how
>   can I count it?

Your can use `findall/3`?

In this case, I suppose you can define a simple element list counter (a simplified version of your first `occurrences/3`)

```
listLen([], 0).

listLen([_ | L], N1) :-
  listLen(L, N0), N1 is N0+1.
```

and combining it with `findall/3`

```
findall(F, person_ate('ana', F, _, _), L),
listLen(L, N),
write(N), nl,
```

you can obtain, in `N`, the number of fruits ated by ana.

Your `occurrences/3` doesn't work (if I'm not wrong) because with

```
occurrences(person_ate(P, F, T, _),T,N):- 
            occurrences(person_ate(P, F, T, _),T,W),
            N is W + 1.
```

you call `occurrences` recursively with the same `person_ate` and the same `T`, incrementing `N`. So `occurrences` recursion never ends.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.